# Raspberry Pi - Python GPIO Rising-Event triggers for multiple Pins

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio, interrupt-handling

In my Python script, I'm trying to call a function when a **specific** button is pressed (actually I have 5 different buttons, each connected to 3,3V and the other end to a GPIO-Pin).
When I'm reading the value of the pins the buttons are connected to **via polling** (every .01 seconds) it **works just fine**.
But I'd like to react to the **GPIO.RISING event** instead of polling manually. And here comes my problem:
After setting up the interrupts/events, pressing one button results in **multiple events triggered**. E.g. pressing button1 also triggers the eventhandlers connected to button2 and button3.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

pin1 = 9
pin2 = 7
pin3 = 8
pin4 = 16
pin5 = 26

def foo(pin):
    print(pin)

GPIO.setup(pin1, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(pin2, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
# same for pin3 - pin5

GPIO.add_event_detect(pin1, GPIO.RISING, callback=foo, bouncetime=200)
GPIO.add_event_detect(pin2, GPIO.RISING, callback=foo, bouncetime=200)
# same for pin3 - pin5

try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.01)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("end")
```

now, pressing button connected to pin1 results in printing "9 8 26".
What am i missing?

Comment: Did you ever get a solution? - I'm having exactly the same problem - doesn't matter which pin goes high all the callbacks fire.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a schematic to share?

Also, likely not the issue but in general you do not want to perform any time intensive tasks in your ISR or interrupt service routine. I would recommend this revised code to judge performance instead:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
pressed = None

pin1 = 9
pin2 = 7
pin3 = 8
pin4 = 16
pin5 = 26

def foo(pin):
    global pressed
    pressed = pin

GPIO.setup(pin1, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(pin2, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
# same for pin3 - pin5

GPIO.add_event_detect(pin1, GPIO.RISING, callback=foo, bouncetime=200)
GPIO.add_event_detect(pin2, GPIO.RISING, callback=foo, bouncetime=200)
# same for pin3 - pin5

try:
    while True:
        if pressed:
            print(pressed)
            pressed = None
        time.sleep(0.01)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("end")
```

Comment: It lacks of serialization protection. I dunno how library is implemented, but it's (theoretically?) possible that `foo()` will be called in another thread.